# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist - Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have a model class that is mapped to a postgres database using hibernate. My model class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="username", unique=true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="created")
    private Timestamp created;

    public User(long id, String username, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I try to retrieve the user with username "adam" using the below query:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
TypedQuery<User> query = session.createQuery("FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username", User.class).setParameter("username", "adam");
user = query.getSingleResult();
```

I get an exception that says:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist
```

My database from bash shell looks like:

[image: database]

How does hibernate map class attributes to table columns? Does it match based on the `@Column(name="username")` only or does it also try to match based on datatypes and constraints such as unique/auto-increment?

Comment: what is the name of your shcema you are using?

Comment: schema name is `myapp`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### Solution

In **PostgreSQL** you have to specify the name of schema like so :

```
@Table(name="table_name", schema = "myapp")
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

### Long Story

you got this error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column user0_.id does not exist
```

because when you create a database in **PostgreSQL**, it create a default schema named **public**, so when you don't specify the name in the `Entity` then Hibernate will check automatically in the **public** schema.

---

### Good practices

1. Don't use Upper letters in the name of `database`, `schema`, `tables` or `columns` in **PostgreSQL**. Else you should to escape this names with quotes, and this can cause Syntax errors, so instead you can use :

```
@Table(name="table_name", schema = "schema_name")
             ^^^^^^^^^^             ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2. the keyword **USER** is reserved keyword in **PostgreSQL** [**take a look at**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| Key Word |PostgreSQL |SQL:2003  | SQL:1999  | SQL-92  |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+
|  ....        ....       ....       ....       ....    |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| USER     |  reserved |reserved  | reserved  | reserved|
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

3. to difference between **Dto** and **Entity** its good practice to use Entity in the end of the name of your Entity for example `UserEntity`

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. I can't put the actual schema as it contains some business information. But your advice fixed the issue :)

Comment: No, I followed your original answer and now there is no issue. Everything is working as expected. We can close the thread. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks bro, using capital letters in column name was my issue

Comment: I'm falling for this sneaky USER keyword every time

Comment: What seriously? I didn't know user was a reserved keyword. Like everyone names their tables "users"?

Comment: @OmGupta take a look here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 7):

For people getting this exception ,In postgres Whenever you write an Entity Class try to associate it with the correct schema (where your table is present), like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "users_details")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;    //long is not recommended

   // Other data
}
```

As @YCF_L has said **Don't use Upper_case letters** in a table name or column name otherwise you will get this exception.

This convention becomes more important when their is a scenario where you have to **auto generate** the tables from entity classes or vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

Should add schema name on the Entity class.
For this example, when the schema name is public

```
@Table(name = "user", schema = "public")
```

See the PostgreSQL Admin view below

[image]

See here for more about SpringBoot Java and Postgre SQL connectivity:
https://cmsoftwaretech.wordpress.com/2020/04/25/springboot-thymleaf-using-postgresql/

Comment: I did this, but still facing the issue: `[select u1_0.id from public.user u1_0 where u1_0.email=? fetch first ? rows only] [ERROR: relation "public.user" does not exist`

Answer (score 2):

I obtained using general names like `user` are making troubles in the app.

I got the same issue as reported here with the following simple entity.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6843302791607583447L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

All i did was renaming the entity from `User` to `Sessionxuser` (and renaming the datatable from `user` to `sessionxuser` to fix this issue.

Schema was still `public`.

Since pre- or postfix some names like `mycoolappuser` or `usermycoolapp` to avoid troubles like this.

Find below a list with reserved keywords and literals preventing using as table, column, and further customized names.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html

In this case `user` is preserved for `PostgreSQL`, `SQL:2003`, `SQL:1999` and `SQL-92`.

Answer (score 2):

Try Dropping the table from pg admin console (`drop table schema_name.table_name`)and make sure your entity class is proper annotated.For example `@Table(name = "table_name", schema = "schema_name")` on entity class

Answer (score 1):

Use: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

In your POJO class Id Field. This thing solved my error.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```java
@Table(name="USER")
```

To

```java
@Table(name"/"USER/"")
```

USER is a reserved word, so it needs the `"` character.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all previous correct answers, I'd like to say that the positioning of annotations @Column and @GeneratedValue also matters. You want to have both these annotations above either the specific field or getter method, but not separately (**not** one annotation above the getter and the other above the field). It worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by altering the column name from `nameLikeThis` to `name_like_this`

```
ALTER TABLE table RENAME nameLikeThis to name_like_this;
```