# Second mvn clean install throws Hibernate exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a build process that builds out the tables and the relationships. Everything is mapped and present and will compile the first time that it is build, but then if you run a mvn clean install again it errors out with the following error (also this is only happening on one of the machines, I am not able to consistently able to reproduce)

Comment: Can you share entire code of Drawing Entity too?

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782399/6572971

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the wrong version of postgresql installed and that was causing the error on the second mvn clean install (probably an issue when hibernate was doing a schema compare)

I downgraded to 9.5 to fix this issue